# How to get all the dates between two dates with each hour everyday?

Tags: sql-server

I am working on something in which i need to get all the dates with hours between two dates. Below is the example what i tried so far and what actually i need -:

```
declare @sTime datetime = '03/03/2019 02:00:00.000'
declare @stopTime datetime = '01/01/3000 02:00:00.000'
declare @interval int = 60
declare @temp_time datetime

declare @tempHourtb ( StartTime datetime not null, StopTime datetime 
not null)

select @temp_time = @sTime
while(datediff(hh, @temp_time, @stopTime) > 0)
begin
   insert into @HourTable
   select @temp_time,dateadd(mi, @interval, @temp_time)
   set @temp_time = dateadd(mi, @interval, @temp_time)
end
select * from @tempHourtb
```

And this giving me following output, which is correct -:
[image]

But the problem i am facing, its taking too much time when i have long gap between start and stop date. **Is there any way in which i get same output but in less time?**

Comment: You're wondering why it takes "too much time" to insert 23,500 rows into a heap, one row at a time, in a loop, and then select those and render them all in SSMS? Why do you need the end of the range to be 981 years in the future? Scheduling a meeting between Yoda and Luke?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, i don't scheduling meeting between Yoda and Luke, its my requirement otherwise i will not post this here, if you have any solution please share,otherwise i will schedule your meeting with Yoda and Luke.

Comment: Sorry, it's not ~23,500 rows, it's actually (3000-2019)*~365*24 = ~8.6 million rows. That's a big calendar. Double it if you need 30 minute slices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should generate **8,597,809** records in just over 3 seconds

**You may want to rethink the year 3000**

```
Declare @Date1 datetime = '2019-03-03 02:00'
Declare @Date2 datetime = '3000-01-01 02:00'

Select StartTime = D
      ,StopTime  = DateAdd(HOUR,1,D)
 Into  #YourTempTable
 From (
        Select Top (DateDiff(HOUR,@Date1,@Date2)+1) 
               D=DateAdd(HOUR,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),@Date1) 
         From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2,master..spt_values n3
      ) A
```

**Which will look like this**

[image]

**EDIT -**

Added `Into  #YourTempTable`

Comment: thanks for posting, its working quite good, could you please explain master..spt_values and i have an interval of 60, which can be vary, so how can i use that with your query?

Comment: @AnilThakur We are using the spt_values as an ad-hoc tally table.   Not sure what you mean by an interval of 60.  Is that minutes?  Would you do 30 minutes?   If so then change the DateDiffs from HOUR to MINUTE

Comment: could you please write query with minutes

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Hi John, I just tested your solution. When I use '2100-01-01 02:00' as date2, the output will start with '2200-12-21 13:00:00.000'. Could you edit your solution?

Comment: @GenWan You may want to check that again.  I can't replicate your error.

Comment: @AnilThakur With minutes, you start running into numeric overflow (max value of int)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Sorry my bad. It was table truncate issue.

Comment: @GenWan No worries.  We all look at things sideways from time-to-time :)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti solution provided by you working fine, but as i read about the master..spt_values, it is undocumented system tables can be changed by Microsoft without warning. So in that case i can't use it, if you could help me out with a query without using these tables.

Comment: @AnilThakur FYI - any table of appropriate size will do.  I use spt_values because you may not have a numbers/tally table, but again any table will do,

Comment: @JohnCappelletti sorry john but i don't get your last comment, any table will do means?

Comment: You expressed.concern over using spt-values.   The ad hoc tally table can use any table.   It just doesn't matter.